# Is there any way to change the value of string property "Contains" at runtime?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There are three filters (pickers) in my xamarin mobile app. Each filter contains 5 options: Contains, Not Contains, Starts With, Ends With, Equal To. So now I want to apply all those filters to filter the data from a `List<T>` and display it on the page.

This is the code I have written so far. It works fine when all those filters have the same option selected which is "Contains".

```
var customer = customerSearchDataModels.Where(x => 
    (x.Number.Contains(NameNumberEntryText)) && 
    (x.Email.Contains(EmailEntryText)) && 
    (x.PrimaryPhone.Contains(PhoneEntryText));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the query into parts, for example:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> query = customerSearchDataModels;

if(UseContainsName)
    query = query 
        .Where(x => x.Number.Contains(NameNumberEntryText));

if(UseContainsPhone)
    query = query 
        .Where(x => x.PrimaryPhone.Contains(PhoneEntryText));

var result = query.ToList();
```

You can add multiple if statements, like StartsWith etc. This method can also be used to change the sorting ascending/descending and/or different columnnames.

If you're using a Database connection, you should replace the IEnumerable to IQueryable, so the right sql-query will be build.